# htaccess if parameter doesn't exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have problem with htaccess redirection. On my site I use url language parameters (yes there is two - lang and country) like this

```
www.domain.com/en/spain/
```

I trying to redirect [301] to default language if user come to direct link

```
www.domain.com => www.domain.com/en/global for example
```

I use this for redirecting none www link.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/en/global/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/en/global/ [R=301,L]
```

This redirects

```
   example.com
```

to

```
www.example.com/en/global/
```

Comment: Thank you but how can I redirect www.domain.com[without lang] to www.domain.com/en/global/ ? I need to redirect exact match www.domain.com[/] to url with default lang

Comment: Divebo , Remove the **?** from rewriteRule line, so that only domain.com **/** is redirected, plus  you need to place thE above code to the very top of your htacces (right after the rewriteBase line so that it executes before other rules in your htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 2 different redirect rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /en/global/ [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.